# WSDL from WCF Issue

Tags: wcf, wsdl

I'm trying to use NeoLoad to generate and execute SOAP requests and upon supplying the WSDL, it doesn't seem to like the imports that they are referring to.

I'm thinking I would need to flatten the WSDL generated by the WCF service.

Are there any techniques I could use to flatten it?

I've been reading:

http://blogs.msdn.com/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/09/23/flatten-your-wsdl-with-this-custom-servicehost-for-wcf.aspx

http://blogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/archive/2007/05/10/414840.aspx

Would this be something I should be trying out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, some clients have trouble with the (standards-compliant) way that Microsoft has implemented the WSDL and XSD.

Those two articles you mention are great starting points - they show how you can get your WCF service to render out a flattened WSDL (which includes the XSD inside it).

The same goes for [WCF Extras](http://www.codeplex.com/WCFExtras) on Codeplex, which also does a few more things in addition (most notably exporting the XML comments from your C# or VB.NET code into the WSDL). Highly recommended.

Comment: No, as their code shows - that is not required. There are several ways to do this.

Comment: It still appears that my <wsdl:types/> is empty. Hmm I think this is why it could not recognize it.

Comment: Which one of those tools are you using now? I've tried the WCF Extras and they did indeed work for me.

Comment: You do have your data classes marked with `[DataContract]` and your fields you want to have in the message with `[DataMember]`, I presume...

Comment: Yes I do have them marked that way. I'm using a tool called NeoLoad http://www.neotys.com/index.php?lang=en and it doesn't seem to like the WSDL I'm generating.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't resolve method parameter:Part: name=parameters
elementName={http://something/something}UpdateSomething

Comment: http://winterdom.com/2006/10/inlinexsdinwsdlwithwcf is maybe something I will need to work on.